# Xcode 8.3.3 Swift 3 - Variable not updating between files

Tags: swift, model-view-controller, tableview, uitableview

I'm having a issue with xcode, since I updated to 8.3.3. I usually work with the MCV (Model  - View - Controller) method, and now, my variables aren't updating between them.

**Situation**: I Have a Model (store all major variables and calculations functions); a TableView Controller (Control Tableview) and TableViewCell (set Outlet and actions)

**Goal**: When a button is pressed in a cell, it should add a row in TableView.

**Problem**: Why isn't table view getting the new value of Model() variable.

To make it better to understand, here is a timeline of what is going on :

Run > run viewDidLoad in TableViewController > update variable test in Model() > cellForRowAt is called and prints ["1"] > show tableView with 1 row > press button > print ["1"] > add ["2"] to Model() > print ["1","2"] > post notification > viewDidLoad gets Notification and prints "reloading table" > cellForRowAt is called and prints ["1"] > tableView keeps 1 row.

Here is one example of my code:

I have my Model.Swift:

```
class Model {
    var test : [String] = []
}
```

My TableViewController:

```
class BudgetTableViewController: UITableViewController {

let model = Model()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    model.test.append("1") 
    center.addObserver(forName: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "reloadTableVIew"), object: appDelegate, queue: queue) {[unowned self] (_) in
            print("reloading table")
            self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

To simplify.. in Sections I keep returning "1" and for rows I count the variable test in Model().

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    print(model.test) // **ALWAYS PRINT ["1"]**
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "buttonCell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
    return Cell
}
```

And my TableViewCell:

```
class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell{
  let model = BudgetModel()
  let notification = Notification(name: Notification.Name(rawValue: "reloadTableVIew"), object: appDelegate)

  @IBAction func okButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    print(model.test)
    model.test.append("2")
    print(model.test)
    NotificationCenter.default.post(notification)
  }
}
```

I hope it is clear enough. 
The point is, if I press the button 5 times, it will add the string 5 times to the array (that is confirmed in the print) but when cellForRowAt is called, it will print ["1"] always.

THank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two model vars are in different classes. You have var model in your viewController, & var model in your cell. Changing one isn't going to affect the other. You'd be best to implement a delegate for your cells, where the viewController is the delegate, and the cell calls it when pressed -

```
protocol MyCellDelegate: class {
    func cellWasPressed()
}
```

In the cell -

```
weak var delegate: MyCellDelegate?
```

Set this to the viewController when you create the cell.

Then in the button pressed method, add -

```
self.delegate?.cellWasPressed()
```

In the viewController, implement this -

```
func cellWasPressed() {
    self.model.test.append("2")
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

I don't think you need to be using a notification, this is far simpler.

Comment: Thank you! That worked perfectly! I was looking for a way to avoid using notifications! That fits properly!